# IndexedDB multyentry with sub objects

Tags: indexeddb

suppose that I have an indexedDB objectStore named 'project' that is like this:

```
{
    name: 'Project name',
    description: '.....',
    users: [
        {
            name: 'Adam',
            role: 'admin'
        },
        {
            name: 'Mary',
            role: 'simpleUser'
        },
    ]
}
```

How can I create an index to retrieve all the projects of a particular user, for instance all the Adam's projects?

I tried with `objectStore.createIndex('byUser', 'users.name', { unique: false, multiEntry:true });` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, keypaths (even with multientry) don't walk over arrays.

You need to pre-process your data before adding it, e.g. for each record:

```
record.user_names = record.users.map(u => u.name);
```

... and then you can use:

```
objectStore.createIndex('byUser', 'users.user_names', { multiEntry:true });
```

A feature request for this is tracked at: https://github.com/w3c/IndexedDB/issues/35